# Prints out the first eight autmorphic numbers

Tags: c

Create a program that prints out the first eight[8] [automorphic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_number). Output must be done
in the `main()` function.

Here's the code I worked on:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <conio.h>

main() {  
int automorphic[8];
int n;  

printf("\t\t\tAUTOMORPHIC\n\n\n"); 

for(n=1; n<8; n++ ){
    if (n*n%10==n || n*n%100==n || n*n%1000==n);
}
printf("\t%d\n\n", automorphic [n]);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

I don't get why it only prints out 0? Is there something missing on my code? Or am I not doing the right thing at all?

Comment: You should explain what an *automorphic* number is.

Comment: Questions and answers should be useful to other readers, not just to the person asking the question. **Do not** edit the question to nothing just because your problem has been solved.

Comment: @Waht: I have rolled back you edits - don't destroy your questions just because you have a solution. The whole idea of [SO] is to leave questions and their answers for the next person who might come along with a similar problem.

Comment: Moderators: Please ignore my flag on this question. I should have simply rolled back the edit, as @talonmies did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

1. You are examining only numbers 1 to 7 (only numbers 1, 5 and 6 in this range are automorphic).
2. You are not storing the number in the array.
3. You are printing only element 7 of the array (which is always 0).
4. You need to expect numbers bigger than that.
5. Additionally, automorphic numbers start at 0, not 1.

```
    int main() {
        long automorphic [8];
        long i;  
        int n;  

        printf("\t\t\tAUTOMORPHIC\n\n\n"); 

        i= 0 ;
        n= 0 ;
        while( n < 8 ) {
            if( i*i%10==i || i*i%100==i || i*i%1000==i || i*i%10000==i || i*i%100000==i ) {
                automorphic[n]= i ;
                n++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        for(n= 0 ; n < 8 ; n++ ) {
            printf("\t%d\n\n", automorphic[n] );
        }

        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Result should be:

```
    0
    1
    5
    6
    25
    76
    376
    625
```

Comment: I think there should be `i`s instead of `n`s in the `if` line.

Comment: just for the correctness, automorphic[7] is undetermined (not always 0 like you said) because it's allocated on the stack. Only static variables are initialized with 0. And your algorithm makes the assumption that the 8th first automorphics are <100000. A proper way to do it would be by computing the number k of digits of i and do the modulo with 10^k. This would still not be the best solution, but at least it would allow to extends the algorithms to values of n > 8.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but not quite there.

1. You are only testing the integers from 1 through 8 for the automorphic property. The question asks for the *first 8 automorphic numbers*, not which numbers less than 8 are automorphic.
2. Your `if` statement doesn't do anything if the condition is true.
3. You are printing the value of `automorphic[n]` but do not set any values in the `automorphic` array. Also, at the point the `printf` executes, `n` will be 8 because the `for` loop has already finished.